# Transform Embedded Video

Tags: flash, actionscript

I'm working on creating a simple projection mapping application in flash for a class. One of the biggest hurdles is superimposing a video in "3D". The way I intend to do this, is to transform the individual points of the video to match the cubes I'm projecting on.

Is there a way to do this? Or do I need to find another way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the native `BitmapData` and `Video` classes. Basically, you could load a video and draw a bitmap of each frame (and do any pixel manipulations you want).

Then, most Flash 3D engines you will find will accept `BitmapData` to create textures. Also, you may find direct video support in some of them.